# Issue with Multiple threads calling same function

Tags: multithreading, kotlin, thread-safety, micrometer, spring-micrometer

I have a rest call to an app twice in my code, even though the call is to the same endpoint , I want to distinguish between the calls in micrometer. For that I am trying to add a new field like below

```
@Component
class MyMeterFilter : MeterFilter {

    var isRequired: Boolean = false
    override fun map(id: Meter.Id): Meter.Id {
        return if (id.name.startsWith("http")) {
            id.withTag(Tag.of("extra.tag", isRequired.toString()))
        } else id
    }

}
```

Before making the first call I am setting the isRequired field to true and before the second call I am setting it false(both calls are async from a singleton bean). But as you can see from the code, since there is only one instance of the class created  the value of isRequired is getting overriden between the two calls. how can I avoid it ?

Answer (score 0):

If it is based on the thread making the call a `ThreadLocal` could hold that state, the `MeterFilter` could check it, just be certain to clear the `ThreadLocal` once you are finished with it.

It appears that you are trying to set extra tags on the `http.server.request` metric, right? That is very clever.

```
@Component
@Order(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE)
class MetricDecoratingFilter : OncePerRequestFilter(), MeterFilter {
    private val additionalTags = ThreadLocal<Tags>()

    override fun doFilterInternal(req: HttpServletRequest, resp: HttpServletResponse, chain: FilterChain) {
        //add logic to compute the tags
        additionalTags.set(Tags.of("app", "bob"))
        chain.doFilter(req, resp)
        additionalTags.remove()
    }

    override fun map(id: Meter.Id): Meter.Id {
        return if (id.name.startsWith("http")) {
            val moreTags = additionalTags.get()
            id.withTags(moreTags)
        } else id
    }
}
```